# Hibernate Criteria - org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, criteria, hibernate-mapping

I'm getting the following error: `org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException` occurred calling getter of `Part.part_id` , but I'm not able to use an instance of the part as an object.

```
String partId = (String)request.getParameter("partid");
Criteria partCriteria = session.createCriteria(PartFeatureVersion.class);
partCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("part",partId ));


@Entity
@Table(name="PART_FEATURE_VERSION")
public class PartFeatureVersion {
private Part part;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="part_id")
public Part getPart() {
    return part;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use part.id instead of part when building croteria.